# Moving website from my computer to host or server?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, host

I am begginer and I always have this problem when I am going to **move** my website from my computer to host or server, some codes can't run or I always see some errors.

I created a database and I set a privilege(username and password) but I have error yet.

This is the Error:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'mypassword'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/qmelkir/public_html/include/connect.php on line 5 Access denied
>   for user 'mypassword'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

and this is mysql_connect order:

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost',$password,$username) or die(mysql_error());
```

How to solve it?

and How to work on localhost to don't have problem with host and server?

thanks

Comment: "localhost" is the machine where you're running the code. For that to work, you need to a) have mysql running there b) have the right user/pass credentials, so make sure both of those are true (which is not the case right now)

Comment: the order is host, user, password see http://php.net/mysql_connect

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). *They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)*. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

So to make it an answer:

The correct order for the params is. see [here](http://php.net/mysql_connect)

```
$host, $username, $password
```

so i guess you mixed it up.

and make sure that your server is listening on `localhost` mine for exapmle is listening to `mysql.mydomain.com`

and as @Jay Blanchard pointed out the mysql_* functions are deprecated. so better don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is the machine where you're running the code. For that to work, you need to

1. you are using the correct argument ordering as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
2. you have MySQL running on the same machine this code runs and
3. you are using a username and password combination that has connection permissions.

Not all of these are the case right now.

As an additional note, the `mysql_...` functions are considered dangerous and have been replaced with `mysqli_...` [equivalents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) (note the `i` in there), which have a different argument ordering (so you can't accidentally use mysql_... functions as a typo by forgetting that i) and should be used instead. Especially if your host has an up to date PHP version, the `msql_...` function calls will plain not work and cause errors that wouldn't solve by shuffling arguments around.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that he reversed $username and $password as per @Le_Morri's comment.

Comment: indeed, and he'd find that out by running through step 1. We've all seen too many questions where even after step 1, it turns out steps 2 and 3 are still necessary though, so adding them to the answer just in case is cheap and effective.